# "Започатківець". Чи є в якомусь словнику це слово?

Tags: вживання-слів, словотворення, невідоме-слово

Хотів утворити іменник на позначення того, хто щось започаткував.

Подумав, що це мав би бути "започатківець" на кшталт "початківця".

Знаю про слово "засновник", але воно мені звучало якось натягнуто, бо говорити я хотів не про якийсь заклад, не про орґанізацію, а про літературний напрям.

Тому я почав шукати слово "започатківець", і знайшов цілих [550 результатів](https://www.google.com.ua/search?q=%22%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BA%D1%96%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%86%D1%8C%22).

Тобто, слово існує і вживається, але у словниках я його не знаходжу (ані на [російсько-українських](http://r2u.org.ua), ані на [англійсько-українських](http://e2u.org.ua), ані у СУМ-11, ані у СУМ-20, ніде).

Основне питання: Чи є це слово хоча б в якомусь словнику?

Додаткове питання: Чи є якесь дослідження, яке стосується цього слова?

Д.п.2: Чи відповідає це слово нормам словотворення?

Д.п.3: Чи є якесь альтернативне слово, яке б було пов'язано з початком чогось, але не означало заснування закладу, орґанізації тощо.

Comment: Є [_зачина́тель_](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=33877 "СУМ‑20"), словорід якого повʼязаний з [_поча́ти_](http://ukraineclub.net/sites/default/files/field/pdf/etymolog_slovnyk_tom4.pdf#page=545 "545 сторінка 4 книги ЕСУМ").

Comment: @follower розширю питання, але основне питання все одно цікавить.

Answer (score 2):

Дійсно, таке слово вживається, причому найчастіше саме стосовно відкриття нових літературних напрямів. Але трохи бентежить подібність до російського *["зачинатель - тот, кто начинает что-либо; основоположник"](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C)*. Виглядає як штучно створене. 
В  [Російсько-українському академічному словнику 1924–33рр. (А. Кримський, С. Єфремов)](https://r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C&scope=all&dicts=all&highlight=on) надається такі варіанти перекладу російського зачинатель:

> 1) зачина́льник, зача́тель (Куліш);
>
> 2) (основатель) основополо́жник;

В [синонімічному ряді](https://uk.worldwidedictionary.org/%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA) до слова *засновник* наведено іменники ОСНОВОПОЛО́ЖНИК, ФУНДА́ТОР, РОДОНАЧА́ЛЬНИКуроч., БА́ТЬКОуроч., ОСНО́ВНИКдіал.; ЗАЧИНА́ТЕЛЬ (той, хто першим починає якусь важливу справу).

В жодному з доступних словників готового слова започатківець не знайшла. Але є дієслово започаткувати, від якого можна утворити започатківець, але при цьому [враховувати](http://pidruchniki.com/68660/dokumentoznavstvo/sufiks), що за допомогою суфікса -ець утворюють назви осіб чоловічої статі за належністю до організації, партії, політичної чи наукової течії: партієць, гвардієць. Але в поєднанні з коренями слів, що позначають дії або предмети, утворюють назви осіб за родом діяльності: шити - швець, грати-гравець, мистецтво-митець.

Comment: дякую за відповідь, вона розширила розуміння, єдине що, чому "зачинальник" і "зачатель" не нагадують "зачинатель", а "започатківець" нагадує? Також уточність, будь ласка, про "штучність", що саме ви мали на увазі? Чи має тут місце протиставлення суфіксів "ник" і "ець"? Грати - грець? Чому не гравець? Треба трошки поуточнювати, коротше, як маєте на те час, бо більше інформації я отримав, але розуміння остаточного ще не маю.

Comment: Мені воно надто схоже на «початківець». І взагалі ріже слух. Але це суб'єктивно.

Comment: @P. Vovk, грець виправила, звичайно ж, від гри апоплексичний удар навряд чи можливий, то літери загубилися). А штучним здається, напевно, через значення початку, що несе префікс за-. Звучить як "стрибок з підвипідвертом".

Comment: [_Грець_ — від _грати_](http://ukraineclub.net/sites/default/files/field/pdf/etymolog_slovnyk_tom1.pdf#page592).